# How to disable CSS editor in Netbeans 7

Tags: php, css, netbeans

Hi there i am using NetBeans 7 and cant seem to find a way to edit file associations or way to disable CSS editor.

I would like to disable CSS editor as it keeps on crashing. To be more explicit it hangs forever on my css files (they are large and full of browser hacks so maybe that is why but still ... i need to work).

How do i associate CSS files with plain text?

PS. If you know how to make it stop crashing then I am using the default "PHP" version of the Netbeans download on MacOSX 10.6.6 on i5CPU, My java is:
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update OSX.  You are a few versions behind.  This is my current versions listed by Netbeans:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)
Java: 1.6.0_26; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.1-b02-384
System: Mac OS X version 10.6.8 running on x86_64; MacRoman; en_US (nb)
```

Updating may fix your issue.  As far as disabling the IDE trying to process CSS files, you can go to *Preferences*, *Miscellaneous*, *File Associations*, select *css*, and change the *Associated File Type (MIME)* to *text/plain*.

If the CSS editor you are talking about is what I think you are using, you can deactivate or uninstall it by going to *Tools*, *Plugins*, *Installed*, checking *CSS Preview by Flying Saucer Renderer*, and click the button with the action you wish to perform.